# Why do we need "Off" after verbs (not phrasal)?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, verbs

Sometimes I read a verb (or adverb) and I get the complete meaning yet I find "Off" (or some other prepositions) follows the verb or adverb.

For example, In the following sentences why do we need an "Off"? what does "off" add to the meaning?

> I will shave my beard off. *(shave was enough)*
>
> Wendy drank half the bottle straight off. *(straight was enough)*
>
> Treatment should start off with attention to die. *(start was enough)*
>
> They ended the meal off with coffee and liquids. *(ended was enough)*
>
> He will drop me off near the station. *(drop was enough)*

I need the the meaning of "off" here so as to be able to always use  "off" in similar situations.
Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in meaning is only very subtle in most of the sentences, and *off* only seems to be providing emphasis rather than anything essentially different.

However, that is not true of the first two sentences, where *off* can significantly change the meaning.

> I will shave my beard.

I will shave my beard, but I might leave a goatee or some stubble.

> I will shave my beard *off*.

I will shave my beard *completely*.

---

> Wendy drank half the bottle straight.

Wendy drank half the bottle without mixing it with anything else. With whisky, specifically, the word *neat* would commonly be used to mean both *straight* and without any ice.

> Wendy drank half the bottle straight *off*.

Wendy drank half the bottle *all at once*.